# How to adjust the size of shapes in order to fit the screen and align them to center?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the app I am working on, I have used PocketSVG to read paths stored in .svg file the following way (init):

```
class ColoringImageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shapeItemsByKey = [UUID: ShapeItem]()
    var shapeItemKeys: [UUID] = []
    
    init(selectedImage: String) {
        let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedImage, withExtension: "svg")!
        let _paths = SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: svgURL)
        for (index, path) in _paths.enumerated() {
            let scaledBezier = ScaledBezier(bezierPath: path)
            let shapeItem = ShapeItem(path: scaledBezier)
            shapeItemsByKey[shapeItem.id] = shapeItem
            shapeItemKeys.append(shapeItem.id)
        }
    }
}

struct ShapeItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var color: Color = Color.white
    var path: ScaledBezier
    init(path: ScaledBezier) {
        self.path = path
    }
}
```

After reading the paths, I transform them to shapes and place every shape as a ShapeView on ZStack:

```
struct ShapeView: View {
    @Binding var shapeItem: ShapeItem?
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            shapeItem!.path
                .fill(shapeItem!.color)
            shapeItem?.path.stroke(Color.black)
            
        }
    }
}



struct ColoringImageView: View {
...
    var body: some View {
            GeometryReader {
                geometry in
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(coloringImageViewModel.shapeItemKeys, id: \.self){ id in
                        ShapeView(shapeItem: $coloringImageViewModel.shapeItemsByKey[id])
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.white)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
            
        }
...
}
```

On the screen, the paths are placed as shown below:

[image]

Instead, I would like to place an arbitrary vector image (split to paths) in the middle of the screen and scale it such that it fits the screen as shown below:

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestion to modify the code or implement the additional logic in order to fit the screen and align the image.

## Edit

After replacing

```
.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
```

with

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

the image is placed as shown below:

[image]

It seems like vertically the image is centered although I'm not sure as horizontally it doesn't seem to be centered. Also, I haven't found a solution to fit the image to screen (the example image doesn't fit the screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `GeometryReader` use the max frame for `ZStack` as follows

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.clear   // this gives full screen ZStack

        ForEach(coloringImageViewModel.shapeItemKeys, id: \.self){ id in
            ShapeView(shapeItem: $coloringImageViewModel.shapeItemsByKey[id])
        }
    }
    .background(Color.white)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. I added the screenshot of the layout after setting the frame size according to your suggestion. It seems, however, that the image is still not centered. Do you know how to find the right scale ratio to fit the screen or any other command to resize the shapes in order to fit the screen? Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`?

Comment: It has no effect, at least if I place it after .contentShape(Rectangle())

Comment: It looks like some paths are drawn out of provided rect (ie. with absolute coordinates for points, instead of rect related).

Comment: For testing, I used this svg file: https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG/blob/master/Demos/Sample%20SVG%20Files/tiger.svg